# Finding business minutes between two dates

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on finding a solution of date difference down to the minute for business hours. I have a table that provides every date and a 1/0 column next to it as a business day. Additionally, I know (not in table) the working hours is 8:00 to 16:00. What I am having issues with is pulling in this column that has a 1 for business days and then adding in those hours and finding true date differences to the minute. On top of that, I am trying to find a solution of off hours time stamps. Ideas behind lets say 7:32:00 on 6/20/22 and 17:42:00 on 6/24/22 with a work holiday on 6/23/22. This is all done in snowflake for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this SQL should solve the problem.
In the CTE you need to put in the timestamp-columns, which you want to use as the borders for your business-minutes calculation. It will then calculate how many business dates are between the two border timestamps.

In the second query it will first calculate the difference between the timestamps if they are not on the same date. Afterwards there is another CASE block that will handle the cases, if the timestamps are on the same date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST.BUSINESS_DATES 
AS 
SELECT TO_DATE('2022-12-29') AS REF_DATE, 1 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2022-12-30') AS REF_DATE, 1 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2022-12-31') AS REF_DATE, 0 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-01') AS REF_DATE, 0 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-02') AS REF_DATE, 1 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-03') AS REF_DATE, 0 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('2023-01-04') AS REF_DATE, 1 AS BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR
;

WITH PRE_INTERVALS AS
(SELECT 
    SUM(BUSINESS_DATE_INDICATOR) AS NUMBER_BUSINESS_DATES,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2022-12-30 13:44:00') AS START_TS,
    TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ('2023-01-04 17:33:00') AS END_TS
FROM TEST.BUSINESS_DATES
WHERE REF_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE(START_TS) AND TO_DATE(END_TS))
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN TIME(START_TS) BETWEEN TO_TIME('08:00:00') AND TO_TIME('16:00:00')
        THEN DATEDIFF('minutes', TO_TIME(START_TS), TO_TIME('16:00:00'))
        WHEN TIME(START_TS) < TO_TIME('08:00:00')
        THEN 480
        WHEN TIME(START_TS) > TO_TIME('16:00:00')
        THEN 0
    END AS FIRST_DAY_MINUTES,
    CASE 
        WHEN TIME(END_TS) BETWEEN TO_TIME('08:00:00') AND TO_TIME('16:00:00')
        THEN DATEDIFF('minutes',  TO_TIME('08:00:00'), TO_TIME(END_TS))
        WHEN TIME(END_TS) < TO_TIME('08:00:00')
        THEN 0
        WHEN TIME(END_TS) > TO_TIME('16:00:00')
        THEN 480
    END AS LAST_DAY_MINUTES,
    CASE 
        WHEN TO_DATE(START_TS) = TO_DATE(END_TS)
        THEN 
            CASE 
                WHEN NUMBER_BUSINESS_DATES = 0 
                THEN 0
                WHEN TIME(START_TS) BETWEEN TO_TIME('08:00:00') AND TO_TIME('16:00:00') AND TIME(END_TS) BETWEEN TO_TIME('08:00:00') AND TO_TIME('16:00:00')
                THEN DATEDIFF('minutes', TO_TIME(START_TS), TO_TIME(END_TS))
                WHEN TIME(START_TS) < TO_TIME('08:00:00') AND TIME(END_TS) > TO_TIME('16:00:00') 
                THEN 480
                WHEN TIME(START_TS) < TO_TIME('08:00:00')
                THEN DATEDIFF('minutes', TO_TIME('08:00:00'), TO_TIME(END_TS))
                WHEN TIME(END_TS) > TO_TIME('16:00:00')
                THEN DATEDIFF('minutes', TO_TIME(START_TS), TO_TIME('16:00:00'))
            END
        ELSE
            (NUMBER_BUSINESS_DATES - 2) * 480 + FIRST_DAY_MINUTES + LAST_DAY_MINUTES 
    END AS DIFF_BUSINESS_MINUTES
FROM PRE_INTERVALS;
```

Best regards,

TK

Comment: Hi TK, I am a bit unsure of how you are trying to implement this at the top of the CTE. The active business table would look like below. 

Date Is Business Day
6/20/2022 1
6/23/2022 0
6/24/2022 1
6/25/2022 1

Comment: Hi TK, I am a bit unsure of how you are trying to implement this at the top of the CTE. The active business table would look like below. 

Date Is Business Day
6/20/2022 1
6/23/2022 0
6/24/2022 1
6/25/2022 1

Now the next table I have looks something like this. 

Accepted                         Pickup  What I need
6/20/2022 7:32 6/24/2022 17:42  16

My first thought was to join and expand for all days between then sum then aggregate.

Comment: Hi Jack, one question: Why are the two days 2022-06-21 and 2022-06-22 missing in the the active business table? 
Aside from that, if I modify my BUSINESS_DATES table to match your example (including the 21st and 22nd of June, which would be normal business dates, so they have a 1 as BUSINESS_DATE_INIDICATOR) and I enter '2022-06-20 07:32:00' in the START_TS column and '2022-06-24 17:42:00' as END_TS I would get 1920 minutes as a time difference, which would be the expected outcome from my understanding.